# How to reduce repetitive code

Tags: theme-development

I've been searching for how to do this for a while but to no avail. Part of my template is using a lot of the same code, i.e. retrieving a specific page.

If this was Javascript I'd set up a function and keep calling the function. How can I call the code below repeatedly?

```
<?php
    $page = get_page_by_title('Excerpts Showreel'); <-- This piece of code will change
// the code below will never change.
?>
<?php
    $my_id = $page;
    $post_id = get_post($my_id, ARRAY_A);
    $title = $post_id['post_title'];
    $content = $post_id['post_content'];
?>
<?php 
    echo $content
?>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do? I'm not completely understanding your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your own custom functions in PHP just like you would in JavaScript.  Here's your code example rewritten using a function:

```
$page = get_page_by_title('Excerpts Showreel'); <-- This piece of code will change

// the code below will never change.
function get_my_content( $page ) {
    $my_id = $page;
    $post_id = get_post($my_id, ARRAY_A);
    $title = $post_id['post_title'];
    $content = $post_id['post_content'];

    return $content;
}

echo get_my_content($page);
```

So long as you have your `get_my_content()` function defined, you can use it anywhere you need to.

Comment: Hey EAMann, that's great and it works. However, I'm having trouble echoing the Title, can you put an example of how to do that please?

Comment: Having trouble echoing the title ... where and how?

Comment: Hi EAMann, see the reply I sent to Chip below with the pastebin.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from @EAMann's answer, I'm assuming you want 'Excerpts Showreel' to be variable, and to return content based on passing the variable?

```
function mytheme_get_page_content_by_title( $title = false ) {

    if ( false == $title ) return;

    $page = get_page_by_title( $title );
    $my_id = $page;
    $post_id = get_post($my_id, ARRAY_A);
    $title = $post_id['post_title'];
    $content = $post_id['post_content'];

    return $content;
}
```

Then in your template:

```
echo mytheme_get_page_content_by_title( 'Excerpts Showreel' );
```

Note that you might want to sanitize the `$title` variable being passed into the function.

**EDIT**

I'm not sure why you'd *need* to return the title (it's what you *start* with, and pass to your function), but here you go:

```
function mytheme_get_page_details_by_title( $title = false ) {

    if ( false == $title ) return;

    $page = get_page_by_title( $title );
    $my_id = $page;
    $post_id = get_post($my_id, ARRAY_A);
    $posttitle = $post_id['post_title'];
    $postcontent = $post_id['post_content'];

    $details = array(
        'title' => $posttitle,
        'content' => $postcontent
    );

    return $details;
}
```

Then you'd have to pass it to a variable to use it in your template:

```
$mypostdetails = mytheme_get_page_details_by_title( 'Excerpts Showreel' );

echo $mypostdetails['title']; // print the post title
echo $mypostdetails['content']; // print the post content
```

Comment: Thanks Chip that was helpful. Could you suggest how to return the title please...

I have this at the moment http://pastebin.com/BzSA2skt (Can't seem to format code in this comment)

It echos the content correctly but the title doesn't work, it spits out a previous title.

Comment: Sure, that's not too difficult; but I'm curious why you *need* to return the title, since the title is what you *pass to the function* to begin with?

Comment: Hi Chip, It's because I'm pulling in lots of pages into one single page. The reason I'm doing that is to abstract the code from the end user - don't want them to see div's etc.

Here is a fuller snippet of some of my code where I'm pulling in three pages - perhaps you can see what I'm trying to achieve. I am open to suggestions, there may be a much better way of doing it since I am still a WordPress novice.

http://pastebin.com/cLPsb74R

Comment: I've updated my answer with a method for returning the title.

Comment: In my paste bin above the pages are being pulled in successfully, but when I add echo get_my_content($title) it doesn't work.

Comment: p.s. you should probably be doing that code (from the Pastebin) in a foreach Loop, since it's all repetitive.

Answer (score 0):

the function **get template part** will do this perfectly.  Just put your code in a separate file.

```
<?php get_template_part( 'loop', 'index' ); ?>
```

With the above, you would create a file in your themes folder called loop-index.php

Read up on it here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part